# how can i run test to render title using jest and enzyme .and i am getting below error Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting below error `Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead` can someone help me?

```
Import { Title } from ‘..’;

class a extends Compoenent {
  render() {
    const titleProps = {
      title =  t(“welcome”)
        // here i am using translations(import { translate } from ‘react-i18next’;)
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <Title {...titleProps} id =‘title’>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

jest and enzyme

```
it(“should render the title of the Page and the title should be as passed”, () => {
  expect(wrapper.find(“#title”).text()).toBe(welcome)
});
```

Comment: Did you shallow/mount the component under test? Can you also provide properly formatted code snippets?

Comment: let wrapper = '';

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<a/>);   
      });

Comment: React component naming convention is PascalCased. Also, is it just a typo in the component signature? `... extends Compoenent`, component is misspelled.